# Token Error for ApsaraDB for RDS (MySQL) while modifying the Whitelist Settings in Alibaba Cloud

Tags: mysql, database, alibaba-cloud

My ApsaraDB for RDS (MySQL) instance is running in a custom VPC that can not be accessed from the internet. I therefore whitelisted only the VPC CIDR block so that my back-end instances can access the Database server.
Note that, I do not have any problem connecting from back-end instances to the Database server using the command line.
I tried few times to modify the white list group and it throws me **TOKEN ERROR** .No more information is provided with that error message. 
This is how it looks like in **Whitelist**

> 172.25.0.0/16,192.168.0.0/16

I wanted to remove 172.25.0.0/16 because this CIDR belong to another VPC inside the same region.
What token error does it indicate? Could someone please tell us how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried adding entries in RDS whitelist settings many times unable to recreate the tocken error that you are getting. however, the format also looks okay to me as you have comma(,) between entries. Do one thing kindly delete the entry and re add whitelist group or try again to delete again the  172.25.0.0/16 using Modify option. Come back post here if you still get the error.

Comment: I have done many times modifying  the Whitelist for other RDS instances on the same VPC (adding, deleting CIDR block in the default Whitelist group) and worked fine without any issues. Since its the default Whitelist group it can not be deleted and there is no option to delete it either from management console or aliyuncli. According to Alibaba cloud doc [ https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26198.htm ]. BTW, today I was able to modify the whitelisted IPs without any token error and I have done nothing other than removing the IP CIDR block which did not work yesterday at all.

Comment: Happy to know it worked for you while whitelisting the IP's.